# Pylint not found in CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pylint

Trying to use Pylint in CMD, verified that it's installed but CMD on Windows 10 says:
"Pylint is not recognised as an internal or external command, nor is it an executable program or a command file".

Python beginner, using Anaconda3 distribution.

C:\Users\username\Documents>pylint filename.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Anaconda-Prompt instead of CMD if you have not added the anaconda python to your `PATH` environment.

You can search for Anaconda-Prompt in windows search (Press `Windows` Key + `Q`).

Then you should be able to use `pylint`, in the command line (within Anaconda-Prompt).